# Write LiveEvent to Calendar

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Is it possible to create a LiveEvent that shows up on the Teams calendar?

Via the meetings api I can create regular Meetings or LiveEvents, however,
the api documentation includes a note that the resulting meetings will not show up on the users calendar. Given it's not on the calendar (and no where else visible?) it would seem we have to control all the settings programmatically via the api.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

We would like to create Meetings/LiveEvents and then allow people the option to manage the settings by accessing the event on their calendar.

The calendar api allows creation with the 'isOnlineMeeting' flag but that makes only a Meeting and not a LiveEvent. I don't see any way to create a calendar event as a LiveEvent?

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-post-events?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

Is there any way to create a LiveMeeting that shows up on the calendar? Something I am missing?

Thanks